# How to make function "invisible" in a class library c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a class library and have different functions inside. I also have a Console application that can access this functions once they reference the class library. I would like to know how to make a function "invisible" so the client won't be able to see it exist and they can only use it if they write it out perfectly.

I have this function in my class Library :

```
  public string custommessage(string messagetosend)
        {   

        string receivedmessage = CallServer(messagetosend);
        return receivedmessage;

    }
```

and basicly when I am in a different program referencing the library I dont want to see this function in my list of avaiable functions to chose from :

[image]

Comment: why not use private ? or internal

Comment: You mean like private or protected access modifiers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Append

```
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

to your method as an attribute. This will hide the function from intellisense.

Comment: Do i place it over the function?

Comment: One important implementation detail for future readers. This will not hide the function/class if you are from within the same assembly, it will only hide it if you are referencing it from a external assembly. @George this is how your clients will be using it so it will be perfect for you, just don't be surprised if it does show up on your own machine while you have the project open.

Comment: @George look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) for a example of how to use it. It can be used on pretty much anything, a class, a property, a field, a function, etc..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain correct, and just another note, if you are using a custom editor, it could choose to ignore it and it would appear like normal.

Comment: Is it because i used the referencing method of adding an existing project?

Comment: @George did you rebuild the library? Did you try to unreference the dll and readd it after it's been rebuilt and restart all editors?

Comment: Okay it worked now, I took out the reference and added a new one.

Comment: NOTE : This will not work if you reference the library by sharing a project. It works if i reference the library but if in my solution Explorer I right click and add existing project then reference my project that way I will be able to see this 'hidden' function. However by only referencing the library i do not see this hidden function